# How to use Snowflake Parameter in SSRS Query

Tags: reporting-services

How can I use a Snowflake parameter in SSRS query? I tried different ways of doing it in SSRS, but unable to make it work.

Example from Snowflake sql date parameter as i have defined the Start and End date parameter within SSRS Report.  In query text connected to Snowflake.

```
WHERE MyDate BETWEEN :Start_Date AND :End_Date > Got compile error :Start_Date not set.
```

Changed the date parameter behavior to

```
WHERE MyDate BETWWEN ? AND ? > Got an compile error @Start is not recognized.
```

I am actually, embedding the code inside the SSRS Query. Please advice

Comment: what about $start_date and $end_date  ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use it as

WHERE MyDate BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of parameters, if you are sending single use. I typically do it with a set statement and a ?

Example:

```
Set vStartDate = ?

Select $vStartDate
```

Then in the Parameters menu on the side of the Dataset Properties you assign the ? to whatever the
Name = ?
Value = @ParameterStartDate

The harder ones and the ones I am going in circles over are the multi value ones. for those  I have been setting up the Parameters section with an expression

```
=Join(Parameters!ParamLocation.Value,",")
```

Then in the code itself I have been setting up CTEs. It throws an error and will not refresh the fields for you :) , but you can add the fields automatically in the dataset properties or write the query without parameters to get fields then add them and not refresh. I just ignore the error "OK"

```
WITH LOC_FILTER AS (
    SELECT TO_NUMBER(table2.VALUE) AS LOC_ID
    FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(? ,',')) AS table2
    )   

SELECT top 10 LOC_ID  FROM LOC_FILTER
```

I am actually looking for a better solution, but the only other one I have seen is put the entire Query into a expression and give that to snowflake, my problem is most my code hits the expression limit and cannot get past up :(